# How do I partially populate a select with ng directive select?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to add multiple select options to a select that already has options in it. Ideally, I would be able to determine the order of these extra options.

In the following adjusted simple example from [AngularJS:Select](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3aselect), an option with no value assigned is included as an extra option. It allows this extra option and keeps it on top of the list of options.

index.html ([Plunker version](http://plnkr.co/edit/ss5gb47dIWHE2LFGj96u))

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.9" data-semver="1.2.9" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
      <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors">
        <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
      </select>

      <hr/>
      Currently selected: {{ {selected_color:color}  }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
    {name:'black'},
    {name:'white'},
    {name:'red'},
    {name:'blue'},
    {name:'yellow'}
  ];
  $scope.color = $scope.colors[2]; // red
}
```

While the above example works great, I would like to do a little bit more by adding some static options that will display after or below the ng-options are inserted while still allowing the null or empty valued option to remain above the inserted ng-options.

Here's a pseudo-code idea I am looking for: ([Plunker version](http://plnkr.co/edit/6FueQDggb1NsU9P6mP52))

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.9" data-semver="1.2.9" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">
      <select ng-model="color" ng-options="c.name for c in colors">
        <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
        <!-- ng-options get inserted here -->

        <!-- additional static options below -->
        <option value="grey">grey</option>
        <option value="orange">orange</option>
      </select>

      <hr/>
      Currently selected: {{ {selected_color:color}  }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function MyCntrl($scope) {
  $scope.colors = [
    {name:'black'},
    {name:'white'},
    {name:'red'},
    {name:'blue'},
    {name:'yellow'}
  ];
  $scope.color = $scope.colors[2]; // red
}
```

When I add two static options ('grey' and 'orange') to the second example, they do not render.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ngOptions with select gives you more power and flexibility for bindings.  However, if you're working with values that are strings, you can use ngRepeat on an options tag to build the dynamic choices and mix that with static choices and a blank choice.

Check out an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KcyRNGr9Oy9ahr7TKlrU?p=preview).

Here's a snippet:

```
    <select ng-model="color">
      <option value="">-- choose color --</option>
      <!-- ng-options get inserted here -->
      <option ng-repeat="c in colors" value="{{c.name }}">{{ c.name }}</option>
      <!-- additional static options below -->
      <option value="grey">grey</option>
      <option value="orange">orange</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked great!! Is there anyway to do an alphabetic sort on the ng-repeat option name?

Comment: Great.  To order by option name, use the orderBy filter in your repeat expression.